# which kind of database to use with android app?

Tags: android, xml, database

I am developing an android program for my university. I am confused about which database to use.

What I want is that when the user is connected to the internet the program will check for any updates in the backend database. If there is any, the program will sync it with Android device.

Let's assume that after while the user opens the program in place with no internet, the program will work just fine because the file is already in his mobile.

I chose Access and created .xml file and by the help of this site: [XML resources in android](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/04/read-xml-resources-in-android-using.html). I learnt how to read it.

Actually this program is my senior project. I dont want the judges to ask me why didn't I use MySQL or SQLite.

Which database system should I use? Is Access the right database system to choose?

I want to do a program that looks just like Univ of Kent program.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing **XML** could take time, also in XML you have no choice but to load the whole file. 
**SQLite** is fast, simple to use and very dynamic.

Android offers a very simple SQLite API. [Androoid SQLite API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)

If you are interested in reading more about all the data storage types in Android [visit this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: does SQLite will give me the property that i want " a file for any update "

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "a file for any update" but SQLite uses SQL queries so you can check for updates easily by making a field in the database contains the date of the update. this way you can easily get the all the updates that isn't in the mobile database

Comment: umm, if i did any changes in the database , will it show notificatoin about the update?

Comment: I have an android application in which i am fetching data as xml from a web service.i have two options.The first option is to save the xml data into a xml file and read the data from that xml file.The second option is sqlite.Which would be easier for my situation. What are the pros and cons? `Thanks`

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your requirement. lets say you want to build something which handles and stores the data on your device locally then SQLite is a good option (you can use firebase as well).if you want to do some sort of calculation on you data on a remote server then firebase is a best choice .
by using firebase you can store your data generated by your users and then if you want you can carry out some analytics as well.

i would prefer Firebase .